# Port blocked creating web app on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, cherrypy

I'm trying to create a web app on AWS and I'm running into port issues.  I would like to have multiple apps providing different services on different ports.  I've created a website (on the same instance) to receive a text query and pass it to my app on port 3000.  The app listening on 3000 is written in CherryPy.

We are using a VPN to provide security for the AWS instance.  When logged into the VPN, everything works fine.  The web page loads, the query returns the correct data.  When I disconnect from the VPN, or someone else goes to the page, the page still loads, but queries to the service time out.

I've used netstat to make sure the service is listening but I'm not sure what could be blocking traffic.  I've worked through the CORS issues as evident by the fact it works when I'm signed into the VPN.

What can I check now?

Answer (score 0):

> When I disconnect from the VPN, or someone else goes to the page, the page still loads, but queries to the service time out.

My assumption is that the web server and the app are on the same server.

It sounds very much like the connection from web server to app is happening via a routed IP address rather than localhost. In addition to being slower, it's also hitting your firewall rules.

Configure the web server to access your app on localhost:3000 and the issue should clear up.

Comment: When I do that, I wind up with CORS issues from the fact that the page I'm viewing is calling a different port.

Comment: ...clarifying the above comment, the server is listening on 0.0.0.0:3000.  The page posting to http://127.0.0.1:3000 or http://localhost:3000 gives CORS errors, but changing to the actual IP address gives me the issue in the original question.

Comment: Can you clarify how the web server is passing the request to your Python app? How are the web server and the app integrated?

Answer (score 0):

I actually got it working.  I have an AWS instance with nginix and CherryPy.  When the user goes to a web address, the nginix page loads with a form for a query string.  When they submit a string, the string is POSTed to a CherryPy service running on port 3000.  The CherryPy service does some computations and returns a result via JSON.

I thought I had opened up everything completely for testing, but I was having so many issues.  It turned out that having CherryPy set 
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" = "*" 
wasn't working, instead I needed to specifically set the origin of the calling page.